# WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Всем привет. Есть некий **UserControl**, имеющий следующую разметку, для просты пусть она будет такой:

```
 <UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Controls.MySyperControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
   <Grid>

       <Label>Некий текст</Label>

       <!-- Прошу обратить внимание на эту кнопку -->
       <Button Name="myBtn" Content="Кнопка..."/>

   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Далее этот пользовательский элемент используется на главной форме.

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
    Title="Главное окно">

   <Grid>

        <!-- Пользовательский элемент управления -->  
        <local:MySyperControl></local:MySyperControl>

   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Как можно было заметить, в состав пользовательского контрола **MySyperControl** входит кнопка **myBtn**, как известно, к кнопке можно прикрутить **WPF команду**.

Теперь я хочу через свой пользовательский элемент управления **MySyperControl** прикрепить **команду** к кнопке, которая входит в состав этого **MySyperControl**, т.е. фактически написать:

```
<Grid>
   <local:SyperControl Command="MySyperCmd"></local:SyperControl>
</Grid>
```

Разумеется команда **MySyperCmd** должна каким-то образом быть привязана к кнопке **myBtn**, входящей в состав моего **MySyperControl**.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё просто.

1) Вы объявляете `DependencyProperty` типа `ICommand` в `SyperControl` обычным образом:

```
public ICommand Command
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(SyperControl));
```

2) Вы привязываете команду кнопки к DP `Command`:

```
<Button Name="myBtn" Content="Кнопка..." Command="{Binding Command,
           RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

(если я нигде не напутал с именами параметров).

Не забудьте дать команде какое-нибудь осмысленное имя (это самое сложное) вместо `Command`.

Всё!

Comment: @VladD, спасибо. Аналогично, т.е. в таком же ключе, получается я могу предоставить доступ к любому свойству myBtn, единственное, что будет отличаться, это только тип свойств. Я правильно понял?

Comment: @sp7: Да, именно так обычно и делают.

Пожалуйста!