# Усложнённый обьект WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно сделать усложненный визуальный объект, например Кнопка, сбоку на кнопке `CheckBox` и еще 1 маленькая кнопка в углу кнопки(Например). Каким способом это реализуется, что бы можно было отлавливать события и кнопок, и чекбоксов, при этом, например, нажимая на маленькую кнопку в углу, не срабатывало событие большой кнопки, при этом что бы это на визуале было единым обьектом и соответсвенно иметь возможность применять стили. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Width="20" Height="20" Click="Button2_Click" />
        <TextBlock>Button</TextBlock>
        <CheckBox></CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

---

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

---

Можно создать отдельный UserControl.

-- UserControl - композиция из контролов.
-- CustomControl - расширение для существующих контролов.

Comment: Э... а без обработчика разве будет проваливаться? Вроде, батоны всегда глотают.

Comment: @Discord про всегда не знаю, а код набрал и проверил в VS 2015. без e.Handled=true, событие затем попадет и в обработчик Click внешнего Button.

Comment: @Stack Как понимаю таким образом можно реализовать через CustomControl? То есть я создаю класс, после чего обрабатываю события внутри CustomControl перехватом, и делаю так скажем переадресацию через внутреннее событие на внешний созданный эвент?

Comment: @BwehaaFox чтобы вывести событие/команду наружу см. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/388977/)

Comment: @Stack Как вывести свойство я понимаю, но вот как вывести именно событие так и не понял? Command в примере по ссылке вроде является всё же свойством.

Comment: @BwehaaFox пример [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=151298), а описание в статье "WPF User Control - NumericBox" - [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/151298/WPF-User-Control-NumericBox)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294992.aspx) (правда эта тема слишком велика для одного ответа). Это в том случае если в вашем проекте нужно использовать более одной такой кнопки.

Comment: C UserControl и CustomControl я уже работал, но вот как раз и не понял как реализовывать такое